# How to find host string?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have just installed Oracle - DevSuitehome2, Oracle Database 10g Express Edition and Oracle Developer Suit - DevSuiteHome2. 
I am new to this Oracle forms, Oracle Reports, etc. During installation, it asked for the password. I entered it. It was written that use your password in SYS and SYSTEM Database accounts. After installation was completed I started SQL *Plus. I entered SYSTEM as username and my password.

```
                 ERROR:
                 ORA-12154 :TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I also tried SYS as my username but still same error. I opened cmd and typed:

```
                 C:\>sqlplus /nolog
                 SQL> conn / as sysdba
                 connected.
                 SQL> desc dba_users
                 NAME           NULL?           TYPE
                 ------         ------          --------
                 USERNAME                       VARCHAR2(30)
                 USERID                         NUMBER
                 PASSWORD                       VARCHAR2(30)
                 . 
                 .

                 SQL>select username,password from user_dba;
                 USERNAME                    PASSWORD
                 -----------                 -------------
                 SYS                         XXXXXXXXXX
                 SYSTEM                      XXXXXXXXXX
                 SCOTT                       XXXXXXXXXX
                 HR                          XXXXXXXXXX
                 . 
                 .
```

All passwords were written in complex form so to simplify it I thought to change any one of the password. So, I wrote :

```
                SQL> alter user HR identified by password;
                user altered.
```

Then I tried to use these while opening SQL *Plus. It did not work. I don't know what's the host string now. Can I get the complete information about users, passwords and host string ? I tried to search for tnsnames.ora file too but could not find out. All files, folders are all mess.

Answer (score 1):

Usernames and passwords:

```
SELECT  USERNAME, PASSWORD
FROM    DBA_USERS;
```

Passwords are always encrypted so you will not get much out of it

host name:

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'HOST') FROM DUAL;
```

sys_context works great for many, many things:

http://psoug.org/reference/sys_context.html

If you have access to the command line you can use listener status to get some more information.

```
LSNRCTL> STATUS
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=net)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.0.0 -
Beta
Start Date                15-JAN-2008 12:02:00
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 5 min. 29 sec
Trace Level               support
Security                  OFF
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /oracle/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /oracle/network/log/listener.log
Listener Trace File       /oracle/network/trace/listener.trc

Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=net)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sales-server)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=sales-server)(PORT=2484)))

Services Summary...
Service "sales1.us.example.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "sales", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "sales2.us.example.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "sales", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/lsnrctl.htm#CIHGHCGJ
(Oracle Database Net Services Reference)

Comment: You can **lsnrctl** like **sqlplus** by typing the command in the command line, this will lead you to **LSNRCTL>** and then you can type **STATUS**. You can also use it by typing all at once in command line: **lsnrctl status.**

Comment: no it is not working. I also tried typing "help lsnrctl". Output is "SP2-0172: No HELP matching this topic was found"

Comment: it is not sqlplus command. you have to use it this way: **c:\>lnrtctl status** or **/dir/dir/>lsnrctl status**. If env variable is not set up than you have to find the command on OS level.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. Mine have little changes in my system when I typed that command. Trace Level - off, Security - ON: Local OS Authentication and SNMP - OFF, Default Service - XE
What does that mean ?