# How can i find the host string of oracle 10g

Tags: mysql++

When I installed it and open SQL+, it is asking to enter the username, password and host string. 
So, how can i know the host string of this.

Comment: have you had a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170125/how-to-find-host-string

Comment: After entering the username and password, this massage is displayed: Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

SQL>                                  so what command should i give here.